# How do I get id of comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a simple blogger app and I'm trying to add comment functionality to it. I'm trying to add delete/edit functionality to the comment, but I don't know how to get id of the comment I'm trying to edit. Here is what html code looks like:

```
  <div class = "comment">
    <p class = "author">Comment by <%= comment.author_name %>
      <span class="creationTime"> <%= distance_of_time_in_words(comment.created_at, Time.now) %> ago</span>
    </p>
    <p class="text"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <div class = "Button">
      <%= link_to "Edit this comment", edit_article_comment_path(@comment.article_id, @comment.id) %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Article controller show action:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.article_id = @article.id
end
```

Routes:

```
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
                root GET    /                                                 articles#index
```

Error I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :article_id=>"1", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question, I'm very new to this

Comment: You have just created  a new comment object, when showing the article, which is not persisted in the database. You cannot edit it. There is something wrong in what you are trying to achieve. How can you edit something which has never been created (and I mean persisted) before?

Comment: @coorasse I was folowing this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments) : When we view the article and display the comment form we’re not running the article’s new method, we’re running the show method. So we’ll need to create a blank Comment object inside that show method like this:

Comment: Sometimes you are using comment and sometimes @comment. Anyway, if you want a working link to edit a comment this must be persisted in the db

Comment: For some reason replacing (@article.id, @comment.id) with (@article.id, comment.id) worked, no idea why

Comment: What is `comment`? Where is instantiated? From your code I see where you are generating `@comment` but not `comment`

Comment: I was lost in my code but I finally figured it out. I created new object `@comment` because there was a form to submit new comment. `comment` was there because of `<% @comments.each do |comment| %>` (I should have posted this part of code here). I confused `@comment` with `comment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You article controller should be look like:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @article.comments
end
```

Your view should be look like:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class = "comment">
    <p class = "author">Comment by <%= comment.author_name %>
      <span class="creationTime"> 
        <%= distance_of_time_in_words(comment.created_at, Time.now) %> ago
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class="text"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <div class = "Button">
      <%= link_to "Edit this comment", edit_article_comment_path(@article, comment) %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Add `has_many` association to Article model as well.

```
has_many :comments
```

Hope you have added `article_id` to comments table

Answer (score 1):

Try this ......

```
<div class = "Button">
  <%= link_to "Edit this comment", edit_article_comment_path(@article.id, @comment.id) %>
</div>
```

In place of

```
<div class = "Button">
  <%= link_to "Edit this comment", edit_article_comment_path(@comment.article_id, @comment.id) %>
</div>
```

Hope this will work for you.